# jQuery Draggable place holder questions

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following simple code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QUBCq/

You can see that I have 3 spaces where items can be dropped and any of the 6 items can be dropped into the three spaces.

**First question** - I place an item in one the spaces - if I remove it the `space`changes to `Dropped!`, what I'd like is to then have it revert back to `Drop here`.

**Second question** - if this was part of a form, how would I bind the items places in each of the three spaces to a .PHP form to be saved to a database.

**Third question** - Can you stop more than 1 item being placed into a `space`? If so, how?

Apologies, I know this is basic stuff but I'm new to jQuery.

NOTE:  I'm using this to allow a user to select their `Top 3 items`.

Cheers,

H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi The answer to your first question is as follows

```
 $( "#droppable1" ).on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#droppable1" ).removeClass("ui-state-highlight").find( "p" )
                        .html( "Drop Here" );
   });
```

For the third question you can refer this SO thread 
[jquery droppable -> avoid multiple drops of the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279380/jquery-droppable-avoid-multiple-drops-of-the-same-object)

Hope this helps.